# How to set the "column character width" of a `bmatrix`?

Tags: amsmath, matrices

Please, consider the following matrix:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
         1   &  -123  &  1  &    1  \\
         2   &   123  &  2  &   12  \\
         3   &    12  &  3  &  123  \\
        -4   &     0  &  4  & -123
    \end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation}
```

When displayed the columns have widths: `[2, 4, 1, 4]`. (I am probably misusing the word "width" here. I hope the question is clear though.)

**My question is:** how do I force all columns to have "character width" equal to 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way. However I don't think it would be particularly nice to the eye. There are optical effects  which are not directly linked to the column widths and a correction, if any, should be done  based on a case by case appreciation.  Compare these two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
         \phantom{-23}1 & -123 & \phantom{-23}1 & 1 \\
         2 & 123 & 2 & 12 \\
         3 & 12 & 3 & 123 \\
        -4 & 0 & 4 & -123
     \end{bmatrix*}
 \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -123 & \phantom{-3}1 & 1 \\
         2 & 123 & 2 & 12 \\
         3 & 12 & 3 & 123 \\
        -4 & 0 & 4 & -123
     \end{bmatrix*}
 \end{equation}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you say a few words on what `\phantom` does? Further, I agree that it is not very aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: It uses the space of its contents (both vertical and horizontal) without printing it. If necessary, you also have `\hphantom` and `\vphantom`. I must say the default is not pleasing to the eye either. There's no automatic solution, I think.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that it creates (or reserves) whitespace?

Comment: It creates a white space of the width of its argument.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that employs the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type. Like [@Bernard in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424327/5001), I do not find the equal-column-widths solution appealing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\[ \begin{bmatrix*}[r]
         1   &  -123  &  1  &    1  \\
         2   &   123  &  2  &   12  \\
         3   &    12  &  3  &  123  \\
        -4   &     0  &  4  & -123
\end{bmatrix*} \]

% "-3.0" means: set aside space for minus symbol, 3 digits, and 0 decimals
\[ \left[ \begin{array}{@{} *{4}{T{-3.0}} @{}}
         1   &  -123  &  1  &    1  \\
         2   &   123  &  2  &   12  \\
         3   &    12  &  3  &  123  \\
        -4   &     0  &  4  & -123
\end{array} \right] \]
\end{document}
```